# How to extract audio form video using ffmpeg in C++?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

I'm developing a C++ app that uses FFmpeg to play audio/video. Now I want to enhance the application to allow the users to extract audio from video. How can FFmpeg can be used for this? I searched a lot about this but I was not able to find a tutorial regarding it.

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: basically my problem is how to use ffmpeg lib to extract audio from video in c/c++

Comment: See the official [filtering_audio](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.0/doc_2examples_2filtering_audio_8c-example.html) example. It passes the audio frames (after some filtering) to **stdout**. It's pretty easy to disable these fiters if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Open the input context [ `avformat_open_input` ]
2. Get the stream information [ `avformat_find_stream_info` ]
3. Get the audio stream:

```
if (inputFormatContext->streams[index]->codec->codec_type ==
    AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
  inputAudioStream = inputFormatContext->streams[index];
}
```

4. Read each packet.
   AVPacket packet;

```
int ret = av_read_frame(inputFormatContext, &packet);
if (ret == 0) {
  if (packet.stream_index == inputAudioStream->index) {
    // packet.data will have encoded audio data.
  }
}
```

Comment: You can save in any container format. Open the ouput format context using avformat_alloc_output(), open the file in write mode avio_open, Write the header using avformat_write_header(), write the data using av_interleaved_write_frame and write the tailer using av_write_trailer. You could also refer ffmpeg/muxing.c.

Comment: i tried to use the above link but line "avformat_alloc_output_context2(&oc, NULL, NULL, filename);" gives an error of  undefined reference to  avformat_alloc_output_context2

Comment: can you write pseudo code so that i can write the proper c code

Comment: You could just have a small, complete example so it would be much easier for everyone to follow.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a simple scripting task... why do you want to use the heavy artillery (C/C++) to swat a fly?

I use Applescript to build/run an ffmpeg command line via a Bash shell. The only reason I involve Applescript is so I can invoke it as a droplet (ie drag-and-drop the file(s) onto the app and have it run without interaction.)

I get that you're probably on Windows, meaning no Applescript and no Bash. But surely something lighter than C can build/run an ffmpeg command line. It's really as simple as:

```
ffmpeg -i infile.mp4 -b 160k outfile.mp3
```

Comment: I doing this to create a native code for my android app.

Comment: OP pointed out that they are making a C++ application. This answer is not useful at all.